# On running bash script from java, only echo statement is executed

Tags: java, bash

I am trying to run bash script from java file. The script runs only the echo statement and the remaining code doesn't get executed. However, when the script is run separately, it works fine.

```
Java Code: Trying to run bash script from java code

Process p3 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(chmod 777 "/path/runall_1");
String line = "";

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p3.getInputStream()));             

while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
     output.append(line + "\n");    
}
System.out.println(output);              
p3.waitFor();


Script runall_1: Compile and run C files using script

cflag="-std=gnu99 -O3" 
rm -rf core
algorithm="fgme"
echo ${algorithm}
gcc ${cflag} -DAlgorithm=${algorithm} Newharness.c -lpthread -lm
Time="2"    
N="32"      
F="2"

rm -rf core

T="1"
while [ ${T} -le ${N} ] ; do
./a.out ${T} ${Time} ${F} # Zhang d-ary
if [ -f core ] ; then
echo core generated for ${T} ${Time} ${F}
break
fi
T=`expr ${T} + 1`
done 

if [ -f core ] ; then
echo core generated for ${1}
break
fi


Output: fgme
Build Successful...
```